Sheaf-structure of the functor of small cochain in singular cohomology
Let me briefly define some notation:
Let $X$ be a topological space, let $G$ be an abelian gruop, let $p\in\mathbb{N}$, let $S_p(X)=F_{ab}(\{\phi\in C(\Delta^p, X)\})$, let $S^p(X, G) = Hom(S_p(X), G)$ be an abelian group, $K^p(X, G)=\{\alpha \in S^p(X, G) | \forall x \in X, \exists U \in \mathscr{N}(x) \text{ open} : \alpha_{|U}=0\}$ be a subgroup (Notation OBS: $\alpha_{|U}=\alpha_{|S_p(U)}$), finally let's define $P^p(X, G) = \frac{S^p(X, G)}{K^p(X, G)}$ be the p-th group of the so called small cochain complex.
In the following i'm assuming the sheaf definition reported here
Now my question, it's clear that $S^0( . , G)=P^0(., G)$ has a sheaf structure, but if $p>0$ then $S^p(., G)$ is a presheaf but not a sheaf, in particular the gluing axiom is satisfied essentially because if $\mathscr{U}=(U_i)$ is an open cover of X and $S_p(\mathscr{U})=\sum_i S_p(U_i)$ since $S_p(X)/S_p(\mathscr{U})$ is a free abelin gruop then every $Hom(S_p(\mathscr{U}), G)$ admit an extencion in $Hom(S_p(X), G)$. Therefore there in a problem on the Locality axiom essentially beacause beeing locally null is not equivalently to beeing null in $S^p(X, G)$.
By construction $P^p(., G)$ satisfay the Locality axiom, but my professor said me that there is some problem with the gluing axiom, and we need to impose fopr example that $X$ is PHH space to recover it.
In the following i leave my attempt to describe the patology on gluing axiom, but i'm looking for an explict counterexample.
Let $\mathscr{U}=(U_i)$ an open cover of X, let $(t_i)$ an a collection of local section of the gluing Hp, i.e $t_{i_{|U_{ij}}}=t_{j_{|U_{ij}}}$, let $\pi_X:S^p(X, G) \to P^p(X, G)$ be the projection maps, if we be able to construct a collection of representative $(s_i)$ in $(S^p(U_i, G))$ such that also it satisfay the gluing axiom we are done because from previous observation  exists $s \in S^p(X, G)$ such that $s_{|U_{i}}=s_i$ then we define $t=\pi_X(s)$. It's clear that, in general there is not a reason why such a collection $(s_i)$ exists, more detailed the conditions $t_{i_{|U_{ij}}}=t_{j_{|U_{ij}}}$ and $t_{i_{|U_{ik}}}=t_{k_{|U_{ik}}}$ implies that there exists $(s_i)$ in $(S^p(U_i, G))$ and $(k_i)$ in $(K^p(U_i, G))$ such that $(s_i +k_i)_{|U_{ij}}=(t_j+k_j)_{|U_{ij}}$ and $(s_i +\tilde{k}_i)_{|U_{ik}}=(s_k+k_k)_{|U_{ik}}$ but the point is that in general $k_i \neq \tilde{k}_i$.
